# CRUD Operation with Microservice using Dotnet Core with CQRS and MongoDb

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, microservices, crud, cqrs

I need to do a POC on Dotnet core Microservices with CQRS pattern and MongoDb as nosql database, I don't know where to start, please help

Answer (score 0):

Please ask for a specific problem and do some work of your own before asking.

That said, there is a rather nice nuget package for .Net for working with MongoDB here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/

Personally I have no expertise with CQRS, however I found this which may help: [CQRS Read models in a NoSql (Mongo DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999404/cqrs-read-models-in-a-nosql-mongo-db)
There is also a nuget package for using mongodb with cqrs.net here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cqrs.MongoDB/

Answer (score 0):

This is very subject question and there might not be any right answer. First you need to understand if you really need CQRS. This pattern generally goes with Event Sourcing .CQRS is only required in some cases where system Read and write has to be separated.

Before you go into CQRS and event sourcing ,  i would strongly recommend to understand your requirements since it will make your application logic complex.

This example covers all of the microservices concepts in a single project .
https://github.com/EdwinVW/pitstop/